# Convert String to Date in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, xcode9

How do i convert string to date in Objective C.

I have tried the following but did not figure it out.

```
NSString *str = @"3/2/2018 11:44:32 AM";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *resultDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

resultDate = [df dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"result date: %@", resultDate);

result date: 2018-03-02 06:14:32 +0000 ,but i need to get it as 
result date: 3/2/2018 11:44:32 AM
```

Comment: what the OP you expect

Comment: result date: 3/2/2018 11:44:32 AM

Comment: NSDate always does not return the exact OP

Comment: if you use your previously defined DateFormatter you can see that is fine `NSLog(@"result date: %@", [df stringFromDate: resultDate]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly parsing the string to the `Date` object. The way it is presented by the `print` is because by default if printing an object, its `description` is printed. In case of `Date`, it will be always the format you get. But the date is correct.

If you want to get it presented the way it was before, again use the same `dateFormatter` and just format the date to string back:

```
NSLog(@"result date: %@", [df stringFromDate:resultDate]);
```

**UPDATE**

If the problem is the hour shift, that's due to your current timezone that will be used when parsing using `DateFormatter`. To overcome this, set explicitly timezone and locale of the date formatter, see this example (swift version, but you need just those two line with setting `timeZone` and `locale` on dateFormatter):

```
let dateString = "3/2/2018 11:44:32 AM"

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"

// set the timezone and locale of the dateformatter:
df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let date = df.date(from: dateString)

// now it will print as you expect:
print(date)
```

Comment: The result should be in NSDate = 3/2/2018 11:44:32 AM . i want the result in nsdate not in nsstring

Comment: @Rajeev what you get in `resultDate` is a `NSDate`, so you got it.. what is your problem then? is it format, or the shift in hours from timezone?

Comment: But my resultDate displays 2018-03-02 06:14:32 +0000, not actually i wanted

Comment: @Rajeev and I am asking you what you really wanted.. what is the problem? that it shows 6 hours instead of 11? or that it shows it in different format?

Comment: Is it won't show the exact time as in the string ?

Comment: @Rajeev see updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Milan Nosáľ this worked for me by writing below code
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to your app current locale, if your current locale is "en_US" then your `NSLog(@"result date: %@", resultDate);` line will print

> result date: Fri Mar  2 11:44:32 2018

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, this code will help you, again that date its convert to Nsstring, check it this code

```
 -(void)DateChange

 {
   NSString *Input_Date =@"3/22/2018 11:44:32 AM";

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

  NSDate * Format_date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Input_Date];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

   NSString *Change_date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:Format_date];
   NSLog(@"Final Change Date :-  %@",Change_date);
}



 My Output is :- 
 Final Change Date :- 3/22/2018 11:44:32 AM
```

Comment: the result is in string not in NSDate. i do want the result in NSDate with exact timings

Comment: @Rajeev you want output in NSDate format? correct